# Bootstrap mt-xl and wd-xl

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that I copied from another layout.

```
<div class="block-center mt-xl wd-xl">
```

This gives me a centered block (block-center) with a top-margin (mt-xl?) and a width (wd-xl?)

[image]

I would like to have the block twice as large, but the maximum I can use is wd-xxl. How can I make the box wider?

Comment: Are those classes actually part of Bootstrap?

Comment: I assumed so...but maybe they are from the dashboard theme I am using...I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the following you will see that wd-xl is 320 width and wd-xxl is 360. If you want to make it bigger you just need to remove the wd-xxl and use Col to setup the required size.

http://themicon.co/theme/centric/v1.9.5/html5jquery-bootstrap4/utilities.html